# Hibernate JoinTable rows are getting randomly deleted somehow

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data

My user-> role relationship table has been magically and randomly getting rows deleted from it. We cannot reproduce the issue but it happens in out production environment. It only happens in prod and only seems to happen when a lot of people are using the system leading us to think it is a concurrency issue. Below is my defined mapping.

We have only a few places that edit Users or Roles. None of these places will cause the issue to occur! Also, no other system is working against the database.

1. Logging in saves the User to set their last login date or lock them out if they login unsuccessfully too many times.
2. User Management - Edit a user and Assign roles. This can add or remove Roles from the relationship, but doing either action does not cause the issue to occur
3. Role management - creating or editing a Role but you cannot assign users to roles in this interface.
4. Users can change their own password resulting in a save of their user record

//User.java

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "user_roles", joinColumns = {
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id") },
             inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "role_id") })
public Set<Role> getRoles() {
    return this.roles;
}
```

//Role.java

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "roles")
public Set<User> getUserRoles() {
    return this.userRoles;
}
```

Comment: I'm still getting random deletes unfortunately...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your description, you should probably remove the join column fluff on the `Role` and simply specify that the `@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "roles")`.

This way you aren't allowing the relationship to be managed by both sides independently, which could likely be why you're seeing this problem.

It has nothing to do with concurrency but an improper mapping of who owns the relationship between users and roles.  Right now your mappings state both sides own it, so modifying a `Role` could have unintended consequences.

Comment: I revised the code above to reflect the changes you suggested but I am still getting random deletes and can't figure out what is causing them. Your approach is still the best, but I still have something incorrect.

Comment: Are you able to include the places where you manipulate User and Role entities in your question so perhaps we could help further.  Without it, its really difficult to assist because we've solved the mapping issue.

Comment: It turned out to be an obscure place where I remove collections from an entity prior to handing it to the Jackson converter. Hibernate decided to save this change because it was in context of a session. Took a lot time and a lot of logging to track down.

Comment: @chrislhardin Glad you tracked it down, happy coding!